# simplexml duplicate elements

Tags: java, simple-framework

i have an xml which looks like this:

```
<A>
   <C/>
   <B/>
   <B/>
</A>
```

in the xml mapping java code i have something like this:

```
public class A {
  @Element(required=false) 
  private int B;

  @Element(required=false)
  private int C;
  //getters and setters...
}
```

but i am getting an error like this:
org.simpleframework.xml.core.PersistenceException: Element 'B' declared twice at line 1

how do i get rid of this problem? solution from anyone is highly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What underlying marshaller are you using? Not immediately obvious from just the "@Element" annotation...

Answer (score 2):

In your Xml you have 2 B elements so in your POJO you need to have a collection of some sort (i.e. a List) for B since it can appear in the XML 0 or more times.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class A {
  @ElementList(inline=true,required=false, entry="B") 
  private List<Integer> B;

  @ElementList(inline=true,required=false, entry="C") 
  private List<Integer> C;
  //getters and setters...
}
```